# IIS application redirection

Tags: asp.net

I have a website registered on GoDaddy and using ec2. I set it up with IIS and installed an application. Currently I dont have the main web page ready, so I would like to redirect everyone that type https://example.com to https://example.com/application. Any help would be much appreciated

Tried using http redirect, but kept looping the redirect causing an error

Comment: You can use URL Rewrite. Please just read this post https://dotnetblog.asphostportal.com/simple-ways-to-redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-in-iis/ for further information.